# Is there a limit number to connections who can be established simultaneously on Google Drive API?

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, google-drive-api

I' m uploading images in multiples threads with Google Drive API. It's working but when I look at the process there are only two or three TCP connections for eight threads.

I would like to improve uploading.

Is there a limit to simultaneous connections to Google Drive?

my code:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (ImageToUploadDto fileName in bindImagensToUpload.List)
{
    var task = UploadFileAsync(fileName.CompletePathFileName, "AlbumDigital", progress);

    tasks.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

```
public Task<IUploadProgress> UploadFileAsync(string LocalPath)
{   //create a file and associate with a folder
    var file = CreateGDriveFile(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(LocalPath));

    FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
    var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(LocalPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    request = driveService.Files.Create(file, stream, "image/jpeg");
    request.ChunkSize = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize * 4;

    request.Fields = "id, webContentLink, name";

    var task = request.UploadAsync();
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        stream.Dispose();
    });

    return task;
}
```

Comment: Can you add any details like:  error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I did not have any errors, the code above work. the limit of two TCP connections, that's what I want to improve.